# Syntax error loading a JSON file into ExtJS JSONPStore

Tags: javascript, json, extjs

When loading a json file (validated with json.bloople.net) starting as follows:

```
{
 "sepString": "--",
```

into an ExtJS JsonPStore, Chrome returns the following error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :    in line 2

What does Chrome try to tell me?

EDIT:

When loading the json file

```
{
 "globalSettings" : [{
 }]
}
```

into an ExtJS JsonPStore, Chrome returns the following error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : in line 2

What does Chrome try to tell me?

Comment: Suggest you read the docs, it's all covered there: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP

Comment: Very good, this was exactly what I was searching for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JsonP != Json, as Evan Trimboli pointed out in a comment, providing [a link to the extensive ExtJS JsonP proxy documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP).

Answer (score 4):

I think we possibly need more code to answer however, if your data is as follows:

```
{
   "sepString": "--",
}
```

This appeared to work in [json.bloople.net](http://json.bloople.net/#_output)
however this is not valid json because of the comma. You can try with [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com/) and it will generate the error...

```
Parse error on line 2:
...String": "--",    }
---------------------^
Expecting 'STRING'
```